# XML parsing of a CDATA element

Tags: python, xml, cdata

I want to parse xml which contains a CDATA element in the following format

```
<showtimes><![CDATA[6:50 PM,https://www.movietickets.com/purchase.asp?afid=rgncom&house_id=6446&language=2&movie_id=87050&perft=18:50&perfd=03012011,9:40 PM,https://www.movietickets.com/purchase.asp?afid=rgncom&house_id=6446&language=2&movie_id=87050&perft=21:40&perfd=03012011]]> </showtimes>
```

Please help me to find out a solution.

Answer (score 4):

This shouldn't be any problem - e.g. with lxml:

```
from lxml import etree

input = '<showtimes><![CDATA[6:50 PM,https://www.movietickets.com/purchase.asp?afid=rgncom&house_id=6446&language=2&movie_id=87050&perft=18:50&perfd=03012011,9:40 PM,https://www.movietickets.com/purchase.asp?afid=rgncom&house_id=6446&language=2&movie_id=87050&perft=21:40&perfd=03012011]]> </showtimes>'

f = etree.fromstring(input)
for s in f.xpath("//showtimes"):
    print s.text
```

... prints:

> 6:50 PM,https://www.movietickets.com/purchase.asp?afid=rgncom&house_id=6446&language=2&movie_id=87050&perft=18:50&perfd=03012011,9:40 PM,https://www.movietickets.com/purchase.asp?afid=rgncom&house_id=6446&language=2&movie_id=87050&perft=21:40&perfd=03012011

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are looking for. Here is an answer based on some wild assumptions.

PS: This solution needs [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

```
>>> s = """<showtimes><![CDATA[6:50 PM,https://www.movietickets.com/purchase.asp?afid=rgncom&house_id=6446&language=2&movie_id=87050&perft=18:50&perfd=03012011,9:40 PM,https://www.movietickets.com/purchase.asp?afid=rgncom&house_id=6446&language=2&movie_id=87050&perft=21:40&perfd=03012011]]> </showtimes>"""
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> import urlparse
>>> doc = etree.fromstring(s)
>>> _time, url = doc.text.split(',', 1)
>>> _time # Not sure if you want this
'6:50 PM'
>>> for key, value in urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlsplit(url).query).items():
    print key, value


perfd ['03012011,9:40 PM,https://www.movietickets.com/purchase.asp?afid=rgncom', '03012011 ']
movie_id ['87050', '87050']
language ['2', '2']
perft ['18:50', '21:40']
afid ['rgncom']
house_id ['6446', '6446']
>>>
```

Comment: i want to retrieve complete data as a string like

Comment: @shaan: W.r.t the code snippet I've posted `doc.text` will give you the "complete data as a string".

Answer (score 0):

as far is I know the [standard python SAX](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html) parser handles CDATA correctly. You will be able to parse it.