# Python ElementTree unescapes HTML entities

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I wrote a simple script that parses XML into a comma-delimited format. A sample
of the XML source looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
<row Id="-1" Reputation="1" CreationDate="2010-08-10T15:50:26.953" DisplayName="Community" LastAccessDate="2010-08-10T15:50:26.953" Location="on the server farm" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Hi, I'm not really a person.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I do things like&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;ul&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own suggested edits from anonymous users&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006&quot;&gt;Remove abandoned questions&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;" Views="0" UpVotes="3732" DownVotes="2275" AccountId="-1" />
</users>
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/gorauskas/fcdd5a064b97f30533da)

The relevant code for the parser is this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as cetree

def get_data_c(fn, columns):
    res = ''
    cols = columns.split(',')

    for c in cols:
        res = res + c + ','

    res = res[:-1] + '\n'
    yield res

    for event, elem in cetree.iterparse(fn):
        res = ''
        if elem.tag == "row":
            for c in cols:
                if c in elem.attrib:
                    res = res + elem.attrib[c] + ','
                else:
                    res = res + ','
            res = res[:-1] + '\n'
            yield res
            elem.clear()
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/gorauskas/655037e96724708492bc) of the full script.

My problem is that when I get the value of the `AboutMe` attribute, cElementTree
is unescaping the HTML contained in that attribute. Ideally, I would like to
keep the format as escaped HTML and simply wrap it in quotes for the output
file. But I'm getting the un-escaped string instead, as seen in this
[gist](https://gist.github.com/gorauskas/b0de8b79d83ff52dc5c4). How do I tell
cElementTree to maintain the original value of the attribute and not transform
it to HTML?

**EDIT 2014-09-01 12:49 PST:** Based on the answer from Tomalak below, this is what I used to get the behavior I am looking for:

```
def escape_str(html_str):
    s = html.escape(html_str)
    return s.replace('\n', '&#xA;')
```

I am basically wrapping the call to get the attribute value around the escaping
function above. like so:

```
res = res + '"' + escape_str(elem.attrib[c]) + '",'
```

Comment: possible of duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153693/xml-parsing-of-a-cdata-element.  In short you can use `cdata` attribute to get this done

Comment: @MaNKuR please provide a code example.

Comment: On a general note, I recommend keeping the code inside the question to avoid fragmentation if the external links rot. You can link to the Gists as a back-up, but I urge you to post the half-dozen or so relevant Python and XML lines here directly.

Comment: @Tomalak Done, code is inline with question now.

Comment: +1 for solving it creatively and sharing the solution. May I ask why you insist on HTML-escaped values? I somehow fail to see what kind of purpose that serves...

Comment: The main purpose is to display it dynamically in a django site... This  is just an exercise in learning djongo with a postgresql backend.

Comment: As a general tip, try not to transcode data too much. The XML attribute contains HTML, your CSV should contain HTML and your Django view ought to send HTML to the client. Having "HTML-encoded HTML" along the way almost certainly implies that you do one unnecessary encoding step along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no escaped HTML in the attribute.

There is HTML in the attribute, and that's exactly what what you get when you retrieve its value.

Compare:

```
<row AboutMe="&lt;b&gt; This is HTML &lt;/b&gt;" />

Attribute value: "<b> This is HTML </b>"
```

and:

```
<row AboutMe="&amp;lt;b&amp;gt; This is escaped HTML &amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;" />

Attribute value: "&lt;b&gt; This is escaped HTML &lt;/b&gt;"
```

Your mistake is that you're *expecting* the wrong thing while the correct thing happens. cElementTree is definitely *not* unescaping anything. It gives you the attribute verbatim.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How to I get just the raw text from the attribute value, without transforming a `&lt;b&gt;` into a `<b>` tag?

Comment: You can't, because the XML does not contain that value. The XML contains `"<b>"` and that's the only thing you can get from it. Don't look at XML as a text file. It is not. XML is the serialized representation of a data structure. The serialization process has certain implications, for example that the string `"<b>"` turns into `"&lt;b&gt;"`. De-serialization (i.e. "parsing") reverses that. Don't let that confuse you. You can only get out of an XML document what actually is inside. (Hint: if you want to XML-encode that string, there are functions for that.)

Comment: It seems then that I need to actually escape the HTML before writing the value to the CSV file.

Comment: Yes, that's what you actually need to do. Look at it that way: You need to *serialize data* to CSV, according to CSV rules. HTML-escaping is not necessarily part of CSV serialization rules. Something like *"enclose value in double quotes, escape contained double quotes"* is more likely to be correct. Have a look at the `csv` module and how it deals with data that contains spaces, quotes and potentially line breaks.